# Why is Young Sheldon's end credit title card numbered #562?

Tags: credits, young-sheldon

In *Young Sheldon*, after the end of every episode there is an end credit title card:

[image: Chuck Lorre Productions - Card #562]

The end card for Young Sheldon's first episode was numbered 562, with the number incrementing from there.

Why did the card numbering start from 562?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are called Vanity Cards.

Producer Chuck Lorre includes them in his productions. The Big Bang Theory Season 11 and Young Sheldon Season 1 started on the same day. But TBBT got its show aired before Young Sheldon.

The episode, *The Big Bang Theory* S11E01 ([*The Proposal Proposal*](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/The_Proposal_Proposal)) has title card number 561. Therefore *Young Sheldon* S1E1 ([*Pilot*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiix-_Ti_bYAhWBu1MKHQFJAmQQFghXMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbigbangtheory.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FPilot_(Young_Sheldon)&usg=AOvVaw3zPeResSxJebHH36SdSp0t)) started with 562.

[image]

You can find all of Chuck Lorre's vanity cards on [chucklorre.com](http://www.chucklorre.com/index.php).

From [Wikipedia page about Vanity Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Lorre#Vanity_cards),

> The unique vanity cards for Chuck Lorre Productions have become a "trademark" for Lorre. Typically, on the end of every episode of his productions beginning with Dharma & Greg (an Apple Macintosh computer was used for Lorre's production card on Grace Under Fire and Cybill) , Lorre includes a different message that usually reads like an editorial, essay, or observation on life. A typical card might include a range of topics as diverse as what the Bee Gees never learned, the cancellation of Dharma & Greg, his support of Barack Obama, the competence of AOL Time Warner management, and the genesis of Two and a Half Men.

Answer (score 6):

All Chuck Lorre shows have such [vanity cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_logo) at the end. You can [read all of them on his website](http://www.chucklorre.com/).

There's [a longer explanation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Lorre#Vanity_cards):

> The unique vanity cards for Chuck Lorre Productions have become a
>   "trademark" for Lorre. Typically, on the end of every episode
>   of his productions beginning with *Dharma & Greg* (an Apple Macintosh
>   computer was used for Lorre's production card on *Grace Under Fire* and
>   *Cybill*) , Lorre includes a different message that usually reads like
>   an editorial, essay, or observation on life. A typical card might
>   include a range of topics as diverse as what the Bee Gees never
>   learned, the cancellation of *Dharma & Greg*, his support of Barack
>   Obama, the competence of AOL Time Warner management, and the genesis
>   of *Two and a Half Men*.

Answer (score 4):

The full title reads

> CHUCK LORRE PRODUCTIONS, #562

I would take this to mean "This is the 562nd Chuck Lorre production". I don't have time to verify this right now, but I would assume that if you counted every Chuck Lorre-produced TV episode prior to Young Sheldon, they would total 561.

Why they're including that number in the end credits in the first place is probably worthy of a separate question, though I'm afraid I wouldn't know the answer.

Comment: Sound like nice theory, will love to get some proof.